# Data from PostgreSQL database at selected time interval

Tags: postgresql

1

I have a table which contains three columns in a PostgreSQL database. The three columns are timestamp, tag and value. In this table data is automatically inserted from log file generated by SCADA server. I need hourly data from this table. (20:00:00, 21:00:00)

```
timestamp           tag  value
2019-06-06 06:00:00  x    123
2019-06-06 06:00:00  y    456
2019-06-06 06:01:00  x    123
2019-06-06 06:01:00  y    656
2019-06-06 06:02:00  x    123 
2019-06-06 06:02:00  y    333 
.......
.......
2019-06-06 06:59:00  x   2232
2019-06-06 06:59:00  y   654
2019-06-06 07:00:00  x   5645
2019-06-06 07:00:00  y   54654
```

I want data between start time and end time at user defined time interval.
Example start timestamp `2019-06-06 06:00:00` and end timestamp `2019-06-06 09:00:00` & selected time interval is 5 minutes then

Desired Output should be like this:

```
timestamp               tag value
2019-06-06 06:00:00     x   123
2019-06-06 06:00:00     y   456
2019-06-06 06:05:00     x   5645
2019-06-06 06:05:00     y   54654
2019-06-06 06:10:00     x   5645
2019-06-06 06:10:00     y   54654
...
.....
......
2019-06-09 08:55:00     x   5645
2019-06-09 08:55:00     y   54654
2019-06-09 08:55:00     x   5645
2019-06-09 08:55:00     y   54654
```

Comment: For one thing, do the x and y time stamps always line up? If so you might want to consider making x and y separate columns. It would make the solution simpler

Comment: Yes. That would also be fine if there will be separate columns for X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded this data into a pandas DataFrame ([with](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) `pandas.read_sql`), and defined your index as a datetime series ([with](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) `pandas.to_datetime`) then you could use pandas [built-in resampling function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html)(`series.resample`) which does exactly what you need

Comment: I want this data through web application. Pls suggest sql code for the same.